how to get jetton_wallet_address in python
I'm writing a python bot that can accept payment in jettons web3. After connecting the wallet, I can output the wallet_info.account.address of the user, also I have the public token address EQBtcL4JA-PdPiUkB8utHcqdaftmUSTqdL8Z1EeXePLti_nK and I need to pass the address in the transaction request
transaction = {
 'valid_until': int(time.time() + 3600),
 'messages': [
 get_jetton_transfer_message(
 jetton_wallet_address='',
 recipient_address=WALLET_ADDRESS,
 transfer_fee=int(0.07 * 10**9),
 jettons_amount=int(1 * 10**2), # replace 9 for jetton decimal. For example for USDT it should be (amount * 10**6)
 response_address=WALLET_ADDRESS
 ),
 ]
 }
 result = await send_transaction(connector, transaction) 

I can't figure out how to get the address of the user token
How to get jetton_wallet_address?
